# APUE ld: archive has no table of contents file '../lib/libapue.a' for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos

I starts to learn APUE and compile the source code

1, downloads the source code from [Source Code](http://www.apuebook.com/code3e.html)

2, extract it to

```
$ pwd
/Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo/C/APUE/apue.3e
```

3, read readmd

```
$ cat readme
Read the file called DISCLAIMER.

On Freebsd, type "gmake".
On other platforms, type "make" (as long as this is gnu make).

For FAQs, updated source code, and the lost chapter, see http://www.apuebook.com.
Please direct questions, suggestions, and bug reports to sar@apuebook.com.

Steve Rago
January 2013
```

I checked `make` version

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

4, make but report error:

```
gcc -ansi -I../include -Wall -DMACOS -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -c -o sleep.o sleep.c
making intro
gcc -ansi -I../include -Wall -DMACOS -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE  getcputc.c -o getcputc  -L../lib -lapue 
ld: archive has no table of contents file '../lib/libapue.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [getcputc] Error 254
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I searched and found answer to add `cp ./lib/error.c /usr/local/include/`

    $ cp ./lib/error.c /usr/local/include/

make clean and make

```
making intro
gcc -ansi -I../include -Wall -DMACOS -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE  getcputc.c -o getcputc  -L../lib -lapue 
ld: archive has no table of contents file '../lib/libapue.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [getcputc] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The error still there.

How could I apply `apue.h`?

Comment: What version od macOS and Xcode do you have? (It works for Sierra/code 8) without any chnages where did you get the changes from?

Comment: macOS Mojave and the latest command line without Xcode. @Mark